# Twitter API: How to change from RSS Feed to new API 1.1?

Tags: php, twitter

Twitter has suddenly changed their API and I'm very sad about that. My PHP-Script got RSS requests and that worked fine for me. It was fast, convenient and easy to understand and  implement.

But in June 2013, Twitter disabled RSS requests and suggests to use their new API with something strange like JSON or OAUTH. What's this? - At first, it's unconvenient, complicated and difficult to understand.

1) What ist the difference between
 - REST API version 1.1  and
 - The Streaming APIs ?
Twitter doesn't explain the difference.

2) How can I get query requests with PHP? Twitter missed to explain that and I haven't found someone who knows how to get query results from Twitter with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this on the WebApps SE site: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45963/42726

You now need to create youself a [new Twitter App](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) and then install the [Twitter-RSS-Parser](https://github.com/jdelamater99/Twitter-RSS-Parser) from github onto your site. Then you should be able to access your RSS feed at http://mydomain.com/Twitter-RSS-Parser/?home

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late but I ran into the same problem and actually created an online service that should take care of it for you. Basically, you can take any JSON v1.1 Twitter API call and have it returned in RSS (XML) format. You should be able to change the RSS URLs from Twitter to the new URL provided to you with limited modifications to your app.

Take a look and see if it helps you...

http://tweet-2-rss.appspot.com